# I want to increase the Inventory CD to more than 30 Characters

Tags: acumatica

Inventory CD with one segment key can be maximum 30 characters. How to increase the size of InventoryCD to 50 Characters ??.

When I inspect the field it shows [InventoryRaw]

For other fields [PXDBString] can be changed. How can I change to increase the size to 50 or above ??

Comment: My guess is you will battle changing a standard field size and all of the components linked to the inventory CD as segmented dimension. The segment defines the length so I would start looking to see if you can increase the segment length and the DB length to see what happens first. I have not tried this type of change so I cannot add much to this but I would personally stay away from this type of change.

Comment: Any workaround - What is the best way of handling this ??. Inventory Part Numbers from other customers, brands are more than 30 characters. Upto 50.

Answer (score 0):

The max length for Dimension INVENTORY seems to be hard-coded into Acumatica.
Since InventoryItem is an Acumatica table, I am sure that even if you did change InventoryCD's length - due to the fact that Acumatica handles its database schema - the length would likely get changed back on a publish, when upgrading between versions, etc.

The best option in my opinion would be to open a case with Acumatica asking them to expand the maximum length within the system internally in a future build.

Comment: Thanks Sanchez ! Currently just worked with a workaround to have a mapped table of 50 Character Codes and printed the 50 Character Part Number in Sales Order, Purchase Order and Other Documents